# $(window).scroll() not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a nav bar and a side bar that is displayed on the bottom on my page when its loaded. But as you scroll down it should add certain css to change the position of them. But seems this is not working only in IE. Can anyone tell me how to fix this in IE?

This is my code:

```
// SCRIPT FOR STICKY SIDEBAR AND NAV
$(function() {
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('#second').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {//background: rgba(999,999,999,0.7);height: 80px;width: 100%80
            $('#stickyribbon').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px',maxHeight:'50px',width:'100%',zIndex: '123'});
            $('#sidebar').css({position: 'fixed', bottom: '26%',zIndex: '13'});
        } else {
            $('#stickyribbon').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            $('#sidebar').css({position: 'absolute', bottom: '-75%'});
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
as I see now, when I log the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` its always 0 - zero

Comment: What isn't working, exactly? Also, take off the `'` on the `zIndex` values; you don't need them.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: @EdCottrell nothing, the nav and sidebar wont change position, nor other styles are applied

Comment: @AJ no errors in firebug

Comment: Two questions: (1) what version of jQuery? (2) are you running in compatibility mode?

Comment: try giving alert inside scroll function. see if it is getting called.

Comment: what about IE's console?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar added alert and seems the function is called,but the css is not applied

Comment: @EdCottrell jq 1.11.0 and yes both compaibility and normal

Comment: @AJ no error in IE console?!?

Comment: how about `$('body').scroll`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(document).scroll` instead

Comment: Just checking - did you also change the `if( $(window).scrollTop()` to `if( $(document).scrollTop()`?

Comment: So you can log the value of `$('document').scrollTop`? And are you getting a value for `stickyRibbonTop?` The code looks fine to me.